# Mass grabing part of HTML source code using shell scripts

Tags: download, http, bash-scripting, grab

From this page, a radio show
http://www.ellinofreneianet.gr/sounds.php?s=0&p=10&o=l
I want to download all the recorded shows.

They are all this type of pages http://www.ellinofreneianet.gr/sound.php?id=7101
and I want to grab from all these 7 thousand pages the line 422 of the source code where the download link is located.
It can be achieved by not line grabbing too, regular expression ".*=podcast/.*" works too.

How to grab the line 422 of every page of that type OR
get the "=podcast/****.mp3" part using shell scripts/commands?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: I edited it for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
for i in {7101..7200} ; do  wget -q -O - http://www.ellinofreneianet.gr/sound.php\?id\=$i | grep ".=podcast/." ; done
```

The `wget` options are `-q` quiet, show no progress etc, and `-O -` write output to stdout.

Not every page has a mp3 link there; Some even ones show a page which could be the 404 error page.
The pages starting from 0 also seem empty.

The empty pages have URLs ending in `podcast/"`, so we can exclude them with matching strings which don't have a `"` there:

```
... | grep ".=podcast/[^\"]"
```

To get only the `.mp3` urls, use

```
... | grep -o 'bitsnbytesplayer.php.*\.mp3'
```

You found out yourself how to output the page URL before each mp3 URL. Here's an optimiset variant of that, using only one HTTP request per page:

```
for i in {7100..7200} ; do \
    wget -q -O - http://www.ellinofreneianet.gr/sound.php\?id\=$i | \
    grep -o 'bitsnbytesplayer.php.*\.mp3' && \
    echo http://www.ellinofreneianet.gr/sound.php\?id\=$i ; done | sed -n 'h;n;p;g;p'
```

The `&& echo ...` prints the URL if the grep before found an mp3 url. The `sed` command switches the order of the line pairs.

Comment: I get "syntax error near unexpected token `wget'"
Sorry but I'm not experienced with Linux.

Comment: Oh, sorry, my fault, I`m using `zsh`, you probably use `bash` - I'll change it.

Comment: Is it possible in the second case to print also the url? E.g.
`http://www.ellinofreneianet.gr/sound.php?id=7101
<new line here>bitsnbytesplayer.php?w=728&h=30&s=1&f=podcast/209TRITi.mp3`

Comment: What is the second case? Does the last line not work?

Comment: With second case I mean "To get only the .mp3 urls, use". It works but I want it to be one line the URL from which the mp3 link was grabbed and the second line to be the grabbed mp3 link.

Comment: I found how to do it,
`for i in {7100..7200} ; do wget -q -O - http://www.ellinofreneianet.gr/sound.php\?id\=$i | grep -o -q 'bitsnbytesplayer.php.*\.mp3' && echo http://www.ellinofreneianet.gr/sound.php\?id\=$i ; wget -q -O - http://www.ellinofreneianet.gr/sound.php\?id\=$i | grep -o 'bitsnbytesplayer.php.*\.mp3' ; done` Thanks for the answer my friend.

Comment: Nice! It could be simplified to `for i in {7100..7200} ; do wget -q -O - http://www.ellinofreneianet.gr/sound.php\?id\=$i | grep -o 'bitsnbytesplayer.php.*\.mp3' && echo http://www.ellinofreneianet.gr/sound.php\?id\=$i ; done` if you can accept that the mp3 url comes first.

Comment: Ha, we can switch the lines back so the mp3 comes second again. Mind you, we're saving 7000 HTTP requests with that. :) I'll add to the answer.